# mongodb text index not indexing

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

mongo3.4.6

I am new to mongodb, and I have some problem with indexing. below I create a text index on RequestId(string) inside recordInfo collection:

```
db.getCollection("RecordInfo").createIndex({"RequestId":"text"})
```

but when I　try to query below:

```
db.getCollection("RecordInfo").find({"RequestId":"4513456313212313212aaaa"}).explain("executionStats")
```

you can see it's not using index:

```
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 1,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 17,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 9998,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "filter" : {
            "RequestId" : {
                "$eq" : "4513456313212313212aaaa"
            }
        },
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 21,
        "works" : 10000,
        "advanced" : 1,
        "needTime" : 9998,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 78,
        "restoreState" : 78,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "docsExamined" : 9998
    }
},
```

then I try below with $text:

```
db.getCollection("RecordInfo").find({$text:{$search:"4513456313212313212aaaa"}}).explain("executionStats")
```

it gives me below, which I think pretty good one:

```
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 1,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 1,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "TEXT",
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
        "works" : 5,
        "advanced" : 1,
        "needTime" : 3,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 0,
        "restoreState" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "indexPrefix" : {
        },
        "indexName" : "RequestId_text",
        "parsedTextQuery" : {
            "terms" : [
                "4513456313212313212aaaa"
            ],
            "negatedTerms" : [ ],
            "phrases" : [ ],
            "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
        },
        "textIndexVersion" : 3,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 5,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 3,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsRejected" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "TEXT_OR",
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 5,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 3,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 1,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 1,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 2,
                    "advanced" : 1,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 0,
                    "restoreState" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "RequestId_text",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "backward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 1,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 1,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

but why mongo doesn't use a index by default, so I use hint to force a index query with below:

```
db.getCollection("RecordInfo").find({"RequestId":"4513456313212313212aaaa"}).hint("RequestId_text").explain("executionStats")
```

it give me these, which is not that good:

```
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 1,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 93,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 49378,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 9998,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "RequestId" : {
                "$eq" : "4513456313212313212aaaa"
            }
        },
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 91,
        "works" : 49379,
        "advanced" : 1,
        "needTime" : 49377,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 386,
        "restoreState" : 386,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "docsExamined" : 9998,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned" : 9998,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 50,
            "works" : 49379,
            "advanced" : 9998,
            "needTime" : 39380,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 386,
            "restoreState" : 386,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "keyPattern" : {
                "_fts" : "text",
                "_ftsx" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "RequestId_text",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "_fts" : [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "_ftsx" : [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined" : 49378,
            "seeks" : 1,
            "dupsTested" : 49378,
            "dupsDropped" : 39380,
            "seenInvalidated" : 0
        }
    }
},
```

To summarize, I want to use index or whatever method to query RequestId field which is string column fast. but if I force to use index, it seems not work for me only make my query worse. but if I use index another way, like below, I can see a pretty good query. but I can't specify on which field I want to query this way.

```
db.getCollection("RecordInfo").find({$text:{$search:"4513456313212313212aaaa"}}).explain("executionStats")
```

Comment: A Full-Text-Search index is very different from a "normal" index. You need to know when to use which, Mongo cannot just decide that for you. For example, the full-text index will only find complete tokens, and it cannot tell you in which column it found them.

Comment: That's not what a "text" index is for. You want a regular b-tree index. Simply `db.getCollection("RecordInfo").createIndex({ "RequestId": 1 })` and then do standard queries.

Comment: @Thilo mostly we query a substring on a string field of a document, which is regulare expression match, what kind of index should I use? and I guess it's bad designed to have very large document which provent me from creating text index because of a lot of term list size limitation violation?

Comment: Text index does not do substring or regular expression query. You can use a normal index for that (but it will not be very efficient, and you have to know which field to search). If you do not know which field to seach in, you cannot really search.

Comment: Normal index sounds good, but I can't create the index, either normal or text index. And hash index performs badly. I am thinking find out all big document and delete them if they are not so many, do you know how to find out big doc ones?

Answer (score 0):

Text search only works using the `$text` query operator.

When you execute `db.getCollection("RecordInfo").find({"RequestId":"4513456313212313212aaaa"})`, you're running a query for an exact match on that field.

From the question, it seems what you're looking for is a regular index, which you can create using `db.getCollection("RecordInfo").createIndex({"RequestId": 1})`

This will make your query using `$text` fail (because there is no text index) but will make the regular one use the index and avoid `COLLSCAN`.

Comment: thanks Kewne, however I cann't create a regular index becuase of document size limitation violation,errmsg: key  too large to index. Also I think I'd better use a text index, because:1,it's a string field, 2, we dont search entire field, we search substring on that field, which is a regular expression match. am I right ?  
If so, I still can't create text index because field size limitation violation,  so maybe mongodb is not suppose to be used to store large document?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The thing is text search might not do what you expect because of stemming and other things (searching for 'drive' will match things like 'driving' and 'driver'). What's the actual size/format of your "RequestId" field? I'm thinking the way to go is to duplicate the field with a transformation (like truncation or hashing), making it smaller and indexable.

Comment: Hi Kewne, RequestId field contains string like below:

{"Status":{"IsSuccess":false,"ResponseMessage":"请求Head信息错误,不能为空","ResponseCode":"0020","WarningMessage":null}}

one thing I dont understand, the document size shouldn't exceed 4MB, yet I receive: "errmsg" : "trying to index text where term list is too big, max is 4mb.   so what is term list anyway?

Comment: since we have index limitation error, we would like to find out the document size of that collection, how can I do that in Mongo?